# aws-s3 gem has namespace issues with my Engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails 3 Engine for one of our projects. To debug an issue I moved the gem declaration to a `:path` statement, as [the edge guide suggests](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#inside-an-engine). It comes about two gems after the requirement for the `aws-s3` gem. Now, when I try to start up the development server using `rails s`, I get an error from `aws-s3` that looks like this:

> /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@xproject/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library': uninitialized constant MyEngineNamespace::Engine (NameError)

The associated bit of code in the S3 gem looks like this:

```
def const_missing_from_s3_library(sym)
  if sym.to_s =~ /^(\w+)(Bucket|S3Object)$/
    const = const_set(sym, Class.new(AWS::S3.const_get($2)))
    const.current_bucket = $1.underscore
    const
  else
    const_missing_not_from_s3_library(sym)
  end
end
alias_method :const_missing_not_from_s3_library, :const_missing
alias_method :const_missing, :const_missing_from_s3_library
```

But I'm not at all sure why this code got called; the engine doesn't (intentionally) touch S3. So... huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Figured it out. The issue wasn't S3 (as I suspected) but the way I was including the engine in the `Gemfile`, which I didn't include in the question (so no wonder nobody figured it out).

This works:

```
gem "my_engine", :path => "/Users/me/Projects/my-engine", :require => 'my-engine'
```

This doesn't:

```
gem "my_engine", :path => "/Users/me/Projects/my-engine"
```

The `:require` parameter seems to be useful in setting up the constants.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100 % an answer to your question, but it will in a way solve your problem:

It's recommended to use [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) instead of aws-s3, which isn't threadsafe among other things according to [the Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting).
Fog is a lot more flexible in terms which cloud services to access and actively supported. Here's a good guide for [getting started with Fog and S3](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/docs/storage/index.markdown).

Comment: That's probably not a bad idea... but I'm already [taking quite a bit of hair off this yak](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Y/yak-shaving.html). Seems like there should be a lighter solution to the problem.

Comment: Cool dictum, I'll have to remember that.